# The best way to handle image in tableviewcell [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, data-modeling

I've table view cell that require to show 10-30 image with high resolution (for print purposes). The app got memory warning and crash when we had 15 photos or so. How the best way to handle photo in tableview cell so the app wont crash?

**Class Data**

```
class dataImage {
    var userId: String
    var value: Double
    var photo: UIImage?
    var croppedPhoto: UIImage?

init(userId:String, value: Double, photo: UIImage?, croppedPhoto: UIImage?){
    self.userId = userId
    self.value = value
    self.photo = photo
    self.croppedPhoto = croppedPhoto
}
```

}

**View Controller**

```
func loadDataPhoto(){
        for asset in photos{
            autoreleasepool{
            asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ image, info in
                let images = image
                let croppedImage: UIImage = self.photoToCrop(image: image!)
                let data1 = dataImage(userId: "goodies\(completed+1)", value: 1.0, photo: images, croppedPhoto: croppedImage)
                datas += [data1]
                print("*")
                //print(data1.userId)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
        }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "reviewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell

    let data = datas[indexPath.row]
    let tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tag = tag
    autoreleasepool { () -> () in
    cell.imageView.image = data.croppedPhoto
    }
    cell.countStepper.value = datas[indexPath.row].value
    cell.stepperLabel.text = "x \(Int(cell.countStepper.value))"

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why you are setting delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath? 'cell.delegate = self'

Comment: that's for stepper, my tableview has stepper for its cell @BharatModi

Comment: You are showing 10-15 image in one cell or different cells? Also try running app by commenting code other than code for setting image to get the exact cause of issue.

Comment: once remove this line cell.delegate = self  and then see if the memory warning still occurs?

Comment: @BharatModi i mean 1 tableview, multiple cells. Anyway right before showing photo in tableview, i loaded all photos and crop them. And show the cropped image. let me add that code

Comment: @anishparajuli yeah its still occurs